# Как попросить fdisk начать разметку нового раздела с цилиндров, а не с секторов?

Tags: ext4, linux

Я хочу указать цилиндры начиная с первого, а не сектора (последняя строчка куска из баша) и никак не пойму как это сделать? Вот мой *fdisk*.

Судя по описаниям в тырнете, там, где сектора, должны быть циллиндры, а у меня нету...

```
root@kirill:~# mkfs -t ext4 -L Fleshko /dev/sdb
...
root@kirill:~# fdisk /dev/sdb
Device contains neither a valid DOS partition table,
 nor Sun, SGI or OSF disklabel
Building a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xb897a0f4.
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
After that, of course, the previous content won't be recoverable.
Warning: invalid flag 0x0000 of partition table 4 will be corrected by w(rite)
Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
e   extended
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 1
First sector (2048-7856127, default 2048):
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут нужно знать что хотелось-бы получить в результате.

Первое: Получить флешку целиком как файловую систему систему:

```
# mkfs -t ext4 -L Fleshko /dev/sdb
# mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb /mnt
```

Второе: Создать раздел на флешке и на нем создать файловую систему:

```
# parted -s - /dev/sdb  mkpart primary ext3 0 100%
# Тут можно использовать fdisk
# mkfs -t ext4 -L Fleshko /dev/sdb1
# mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

Если есть желание "очистить" таблицу разделов, то можно сделать:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Дык не надо потому что создавать файловую систему на диске с пустой таблицей разделов. Первый шаг, ваш вам все и испортил.